# Typescript interface extends

Tags: typescript

I have a question about extending typescript interface, the class property 'value' isn't recognized as array!

The code example:

```
export class InListFilter<T, D=T[]> extends BaseFilter<T, D> {

    constructor(props: Partial<BaseFilter<T>>) {
        super(props);
    }

    getValue(): string {

        let s: string[] = [];

        if (this.value && this.value.length) {  // <- Property length does not exist on type D
            for (let v of this.value) {
                v = this.getValueParsed(v);
                s.push(this.enquoted ? `'${v}'` : `${v}`);
            }
        }

        return s && s.length ? s.join(',') : '';
    }

    render(): string {

        let s: string = '';

        if (!this.field || !this.hasValue()) {
            return s;
        }

        return `(${this.field} IN (${this.getValue()}))`;
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [TypeScript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)'s description of constraints on generics:

> use ... `extends` keyword to denote ... constraint

So constraint in your example would be:

```
export class InListFilter<T, D extends T[]> extends BaseFilter<T, D> {
```